# What visa for a short term course in the USA?

Tags: united-states, visa, training

There is a short term course in the USA in August I really want to attend.
It's a 1 week training at the University of Minnesota. However, I'm not going to enroll as a student at the university.

May I use the B1 visa to do so? Has anyone been in a similar situation?

Answer (score 2):

I am not a lawyer and this is not legal advice, but my understanding is that B1 visas are typically the right visa for academic conferences and similar events.  See [this document](https://travel.state.gov/content/dam/visas/BusinessVisa%20Purpose%20Listings%20March%202014%20flier.pdf) from the US government, particularly the entries on “Conference, meeting, trade show, or business event attendee” and “training.”

Comment: Thanks @Noah ! You are right. 
I found (in Vietnam) a guy who attended the last year edition of this training. He used the B1 visa.
So, for this very specific situation the B1 visa applies.